# rewrite only pagination number 1

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have a website which has lots of categories with a maximum of 4 deep.

So:

`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA`
In these categories I have multiple pages defined by pagination...

So:
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/1`
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/2`
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/3`

But
 
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/1`
is exactly the same as:
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/`

Now I want to write a rewrite rule that will only redirect the page with pagination 1
So:
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/1`
Has to be send to
`www.website.nl/catA/subcatA/subsubcatA/`

This should be for all categories and subcategories. And ONLY page 1... the other pages should show 2 and 3 and 4....

Is this possible
I am working with apache mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that are already there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/1/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Wow Thanks! I didn't expect you to write a complete working answer.. But this is great. It works flawlessly. Thanks Allot!